# IKEV2 IPSEC Autostart, restart, daemon

Tags: linux, ipsec, site-to-site-vpn, strongswan

I use strongswan for IKEV2 and IPSEC.
And i don't know how to keep it updated, and running on change restart etc.

1. For starting service i use:

   **systemctl status strongswan**
2. Afer that i need to type

   **ipsec up vpn**

When 1 side was disconect from network or any other reason i need every time type  **ipsec up vpn**...

Is any options to make some automatically updated?

Ubuntu 18

```
/etc/ipsec.conf
# ipsec.conf - strongSwan IPsec configuration file

# basic configuration

config setup
    charondebug="ike 1, knl 1, cfg 0"
    uniqueids=no

conn vpn
     compress=no
     type=tunnel
     keyexchange=ikev2
     ike=aes256-sha256-modp2048
     esp=aes256-sha256-modp2048
     ikelifetime = 24h
     lifetime = 30m
     dpddelay = 120s
     left=%any
     leftsourceip=%config
     leftcert=/etc/ipsec.d/certs/client1.crt
     leftid=client1@xxxxxxx
     leftfirewall=yes
     right=xxxxxxx
     rightsubnet=172.2.0.0/18
     rightid="CN=xxxxxxxx" 
     rightauth=eap-mschapv2
     auto=add
     eap_identity=%identity
```

One side is Mikrotik CCR other side is Ubuntu 18, both have IP without NAT traversal.

VPN work, i just need to know how to create automatic start on UBUNTU to start and keep VPN up if they reset or etc.

Comment: I assume you are using `/etc/ipsec.conf` and **stroke** to configure **strongswan**. Can you add `/etc/ipsec.conf` to your question? Can you add more about the tunnel endpoints: are they both running Ubuntu? Do they both have a public IP or one is behind a NAT? That information will help to give a better suited answer. BTW: it is called IKE, not IKV.

Comment: its done @PiotrP.Karwasz

Answer (score 3):

I assume that **strongswan** starts on reboot, since you don't mention using `systemctl start strongswan` (the command you cite `systemctl status strongswan` just tells you whether the service is running). If that's not the case, you need to enable the service:

```
systemctl enable strongswan
```

In the [conn section](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ConnSection) you need to specify what should **strongswan** do when it starts and when the remote peer closes the connection or dies. So add something like:

```
auto=start
dpdaction=hold
closeaction=hold
```

The meaning of the actions is explained in the [manual page](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ConnSection). Basically you want your tunnel to get up on server boot, while if the tunnel is closed intentionally (**closeaction**) or because of network problems (**dpdaction**) **strongswan** will install a trap that will try to bring it back next time it is needed, leaving time to the other peer to recover.